# Elvis twin brother probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a following problem to solve:
**Identical twins are 8% of all twins. Elvis Presley had a twin brother who died at birth. What is the probability that Elvis was an identical twin?**
My idea of solving it is to use Bayes Theorem, but I'm not quite sure if I do it correctly.
In my solution
**P(A)**-probabilty of being an identical twin brother
**P(B)**-probability of having an identical twin brother
**P(A|B)**=?
From Bayes Theorem:
**P(A|B)=P(A)∗P(B|A)/P(B)**
**P(A)**=0.08
**P(B|A)**=1
**P(B)**=0.92*0.5 as we have got 50% chances of being a boy.
Is it correct?

Comment: You should delete https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739772/elvis-presley-identical-twin-probability-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run $100$ tests.  Of those, $8$ will be identical twins and the remaining $92$ will be non-identical twins.  We assume that if the twins are not identical, there was *a priori* a $50$% probability that the other twin was a boy, so $46$ non-identical twins will be boys and the rest will be girls.

We know that Elvis's twin was a boy.  Therefore, of the $54$ trials in which the other twin was a boy, the twin was identical in $8$ of them, so the probability that Elvis's twin was identical was $$\frac{4}{27}=0.\overline{148}.$$